# How to insert circle at crossroads table?

Tags: html, css

How to insert circle at crossroads table, or use image (table) from layout?

[image: this table on img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a circle on top of the border, use :before css property. for [example](https://codepen.io/rj99/pen/yvvWYK)

```
 div{
  border-right: solid white 1px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius:100px;
    margin-left:290px ;
}
```

It will help you to get the design like image with some modification.